# Not able to preview 50MB image in Chrome using FileReader()

Tags: google-chrome, file-upload

```js
filesSelectedOrDropped(evt) {
  this.imageError = '';
  let selectedFiles = [];
  if (evt.type === 'drop') {
    selectedFiles = evt.dataTransfer.files;
  } else if (evt.type === 'change') {
    selectedFiles = evt.target.files;
  }

  if (selectedFiles && selectedFiles[0]) {
    const file = selectedFiles[0];
    let fileObject: any;

    if (file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image') {
        this.imageError = `Only images are allowed.`;
        return false;
    }

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      const image = new Image();
      image.src = e.target.result;
      image.onload = rs => {
        this.imageBase64 = e.target.result;
        const array = this.imageBase64.split(',');
        const mime = array[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
        const bstr = atob(array[1]);
        let n = bstr.length;
        const u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
        while (n--) {
          u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
        }

        fileObject = new File([u8arr], 'image.' + mime.split('/')[1], { type: mime });

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', fileObject);
        formData.append('type', 'image');

        // API call to upload image.
     };
   };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 }
}
```

I'm using above method to upload an image to server and also need to show preview before uploading. Above method works fine for small images around 20MB. But, for 50MB images, I'm getting console warning `[Violation] 'load' handler took 800ms` and nothing happens. I tried to console inside `image.onload = rs => {}` function but code execution is not reaching there. While the same code works in Firefox.

Comment: Why are you recreating the file, you still have access to the original file, also you should use a blob url to display file instead of a data url.

Comment: I tried with blob url, but blob url is not getting loaded in browser with error 'Not found' in Chrome and 'Security issues' in Firefox. I'm sanitizing that url though.